# curl using php for box view api

Tags: php, curl, php-extension

Hi I am new to cURL and I don't know how to use it in PHP. I have tried a lot and still in the position where I started. I am trying to do really simple task. Can anyone help me in converting the below cURL command into PHP code....

Please help...

cURL code:

```
curl https://view-api.box.com/1/documents 

-H "Authorization: Token YOUR_API_KEY" 

-H "Content-Type: application/json" 

-d '{"url": "https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/4qhegqxubg8ox0uj5ys8.pdf"}' 

-X POST
```

I need the exact same code to be implemented using PHP. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am not totally sure if you should get a response from this call but if you do this should work:

```
<?php

    //Set header information
    $headers = array(
        "POST  HTTP/1.1",
        "Content-type: application/json;",
        "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY"
    );

    //Initialize a curl connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Defines that you get an answer back
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //Sets the url to call
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cloud.box.com/shared/static/4qhegqxubg8ox0uj5ys8.pdf');

    //Gives additional headers
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    //Executes the curl call
    $retrieved_data = curl_exec($ch);

    //Closes the connection
    curl_close($ch);


    //$retrieved_data contains the answer from the curl call
    print_r($retrieved_data);

    ?>
```

If you don't need a response comment the line with the returntransfer out.

Let me know if it didn't work or it did work :)

Comment: Nope.. not working. I am just getting an empty screen & no errors also.

Comment: @user2607921 Would you just like to download the file or also do something else?

Comment: When I upload this file. The Box View Api returns me a file id. I want it. I will be using it further.

Comment: @user2607921 Oke but the link you put in your example links to a pdf document, so you would need to give the link that you get after you upload it. Or do you also need help with uploading ?

Comment: From that link, the api uploads the doc to BoxView which then converts it into HTML5 which can be used to embed in website page. So here I am trying to upload the doc from the mentioned location to BoxView Server which returns me a doc-id this doc id I can use to embed in my site.